# react filter from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

there
I have a question.I use the code with **Project.jsx** and **ProductList.jsx**
When I use the code it always reply me Error:

*Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Products`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
at Product (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1754:5)
at Products (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1904:5)
at div
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:168591:6)
at ProductList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3832:81)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161129:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161578:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161509:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:159730:5)
at App*

here are my code:
**Products.jsx**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Styled from 'styled-components';
import { popProducts } from '../../assets/data'
import Product from './Product';
import axios from "axios"
const Container = Styled.section`
margin: .5rem;
display:flex;
padding:.5rem;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content: space-between;

`;

const Products = ({ cate, filters, sort }) => {
  console.log(cate, filters, sort)
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        cate ? `http://localhost:8000/api/products?category=${cate}`
          : "http://localhost:8000/api/products")
        .then(
          function (res) {
            setProducts(res.data);
            console.log(res)
          }
        ).catch(
          function (err) {
            console.log(err)
          });
    }
    getProducts();
  }, [cate]);
  // console.log(filteredProducts)

  useEffect(() => {
    cate && setFilteredProducts(
      products.filter((item) => Object.entries(filters).every(([value, key]) => {
        return (
          item[key] === (value)

        )
      })

      )
    )
  }, [products, cate, filters])


  return (
    <Container >
      {filteredProducts.map((item) => (
        <Product item={item} key={item.id} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Products
```

**ProjectList.jsx**

```
import Announcement from '../components/announcement/Announcement';
import React from 'react'
import Styled from 'styled-components';
import Navbar from '../components/navbar/Nav'
import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer';
import Products from '../components/product/Products';
import NewsLetter from '../components/newsLetter/NewsLetter';
import { mobile } from './../responsive'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
const Container = Styled.div`
text-transform:uppercase;

`;
const Title = Styled.h1`
margin:2rem;
`;
const FilterContainer = Styled.div`
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;

`;
const Filter = Styled.div`
margin:2rem;
${mobile({ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" })}

`;
const FilterText = Styled.span`

font-size:1.2rem;
font-weight:600;
margin-right:1.5rem;
${mobile({ fontSize: ".8rem", marginRight: "0" })}

`;
const Select = Styled.select`
padding:1rem;
margin-right:1.5rem;
${mobile({ margin: "1rem 0" })}

`;
const Option = Styled.option`

`;
const ProductList = () => {

    //回傳路徑
    const location = useLocation();
    const cate = location.pathname.split("/")[2];

    //設定selector的值，並且回傳
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
    const [sort, setSort] = useState("newest");

    const handleFilters = (e) => {

        const value = e.target.value;
        setFilters({
            ...filters,
            [e.target.name]: value,
        });
    };
    console.log(filters)

    return (
        <Container>
            <Navbar />
            <Announcement />
            <Title>Dresses</Title>

            <FilterContainer>
                <Filter><FilterText>Filter Products:</FilterText>
                    <Select name="color" onChange={handleFilters}>
                        <Option disabled>Color</Option>
                        <Option>black</Option>
                        <Option>white</Option>
                        <Option>green</Option>
                        <Option>wheat</Option>
                        <Option>red</Option>
                        <Option>blue</Option>

                    </Select>
                    <Select name="size" onChange={handleFilters}>
                        <Option disabled>Size</Option>
                        <Option>XS</Option>
                        <Option>S</Option>
                        <Option>M</Option>
                        <Option>L</Option>
                        <Option>XL</Option>

                    </Select></Filter>
                <Filter><FilterText>Sort Products:
                    <Select onChange={(e)=>setSort(e.target.value)}>
                        <Option value="newest">Newest</Option>
                        <Option value="asc">Price(asc)</Option>
                        <Option value="desc">Price(desc)</Option>


                    </Select></FilterText></Filter>

            </FilterContainer>
            <Products cate={cate} filters={filters} sort={sort}/>
            <NewsLetter />
            <Footer />

        </Container>
    )
}

export default ProductList
```

Comment: Did you try reading the link from the [Warning](https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys) ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It’s react-jsx -dev-runtime/development.js:87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB uses ***_id*** attribute instead of the ***id*** attribute. So, you should use ***key={item._id}***. I think it will work.

```
<Container >
  {filteredProducts.map((item) => (
    <Product item={item} key={item._id} />
  ))}
</Container>
```

Comment: You have to tell what types of issues you are facing elaborately with proper code and errors. Otherwise, it is very difficult to help.

Comment: excuse me,do you know why the question  Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at Navigate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161563:5)